# How to invoke c_str() for std::string variadic template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, variadic-templates

I have a method that accepts format string + arguments (right as printf()), however, I'm using variadic templates for this purpose:

```
template<typename... Args>
static void log(const char* pszFmt, Args&&... args)
{
    doSomething(pszFmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Some of args can be std::string instances. Is it possible to make sure that doSomething will never accept std::string, but will always accept `const char*` instead of each source `std::string` passed to `log()`?

In other words, I need a way to forward all the `args` to `doSomething()` making all the `std::string` arguments substituted with what `std::string::c_str()` returns.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your own "forwarding" method:

```cpp
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) myForward(T&& t)
{
    return t;
}

template<>
decltype(auto) myForward(std::string& t)
{
    return t.c_str();
}


template<>
decltype(auto) myForward(std::string&& t)
{
    return t.c_str();
}


template<typename... Args>
static void log(const char* pszFmt, Args&&... args)
{
    doSomething(pszFmt, myForward<Args>(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

Comment: You still need to `std::forward` `args` or else they'll turn into lvalue refs.

Comment: Returning `auto` will return by value. Always. Better to return `T&&`.

Comment: You both are right, I need `decltype(auto)` and  `std::forward`, I edited my answer

Comment: You need two overloads for `myForward(T&&)`, not the `string` version. It's enough to take `string` by `const&`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution. If your logger simply prints each argument and doesn't "store" it, then there's no need to perfect-forward the arguments, a simple pass-by-reference will suffice.

In that case you can simply overload or specialize the printer function for various "printable" types.

```
template <class T>
decltype(auto) printer(T const& t) {
    return t;
}

inline const char* printer(std::string const& t) {
    return t.c_str();
}

template<typename... Args>
void log(const char* pszFmt, Args const&... args) {
    printf(pszFmt, printer(args)...);
}

int main() {
    std::string str{"xyz"};
    log("%s %s %s\n", "abc", std::string("def"), str);
}
```

Note: the non-template overload will always be preferred during overload resolution.

Comment: Also great and minimalistic solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**C++17 version**

You can use SFINAE to achieve this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template <typename, typename = void>
struct has_c_str : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_c_str<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::c_str)>> : std::is_same<char const*, decltype(std::declval<T>().c_str())>
{};

template <typename StringType,
          typename std::enable_if<has_c_str<StringType>::value, StringType>::type* = nullptr>
static void log(const char* pszFmt, StringType const& arg) {
    std::cout << "std::string version" << std::endl;
}

template <typename StringType,
          typename std::enable_if<!has_c_str<StringType>::value, StringType>::type* = nullptr>
static void log(const char* pszFmt, StringType arg) {
    std::cout << "const char * version" << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Args>
static void log(const char* pszFmt, Args&&... args) {
    log(pszFmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    log("str", std::string("aa")); // output: std::string version
    log("str", "aa");              // output: const char * version
    return 0;
}
```

Full demo [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsQAZlKtmtUMgCkAJgBCM2aQDOmdsgJ46lTLXQBhVKwCuAW1ohppHegAyeWpgBypgEaZiQ4QAdUSwptoDYzMuUh8/DTo7B2cTNw9OZVVMdQCGAmZiAiDTc0sVNUjadMyCaKdXd09lDKyckMSlWrL7CriqzgBKZVQjYmQOAHIZQXtkYywAaklBPU0m4kxmExnsSQAGAEERsYnMadmjDVZCAE9Vje3pUdpxoymZvQX7YAuty4JMEy9RT4O9AinLw6ZaYUiTQHA2igg4AEUmADdUHh0G9NgsjOpJghmEoAPrIPELSYgSZNdAgEBUNgqPGQ/aSADs8kZsJm8neW0%2B31%2BDNm9OhJn2ABU0RisTj8YSFo9heDyZSkSi6Y8sON6RAZAA2YWU6UEYidC6CbAkskECkgPD4pSgx7IHHESZoWhNABU4LVrA1CpAXoRbFlqwgnQAdPriCGjSbLkyWWzBBztlyvj9mH9HgKYeliC9hUCwZdJsWS6Ws0LzZaQS52Hi8FRHpKCUSDY8c3mC6tFWwjGDJu3xPngV2QPS3XDJrQjKxWF5WzGtk103hkIjkehJqxUMAIC6ms7HeOvEoAF4AMRMBHBA%2BAQ/2mWAnWmzKLJd9aCO/0e02k0l9z3ERF3D8OgZGkL9ZkrSlrFYdlY1ZWMUx5dM%2BQBAtBX2G871IV9SzLdCYV9ata3rR4wDAJsIzbA0O2HE1u2MPssM7ejRwLccZnhKcZznYgxQyDRVyVDctx3PcCAPTIj1PC8r37GjBwLSYHyfONcKglBegkx5vzA8TJKdccEWAgIwIgvQNJguD3gQzlNm5NMM35AihVDNzJk2YhgCUfjlyE9dN23Xc6H3B0pMmY9z0vcFPO87VtTc0NlK8pRVJfLZS1EiBItk%2BULUpGhiAAd0yVFZlinyTQgB9UsS6MkyZNk7PsCSTGYewQ2fJNMqCsCZV/PLLQAncwOYZgwM6er1KyvrWwGn9pDGibrM2UtFgIPpaEmdYVsawZulYEBBgAVkGUhzEGdYztQI69AUBQyV6foGWuQQzoII6rsm0gECWLAPBDUgAGsQGO9YRCO7gzouq7SBuwYzqUEBwY%2By79tIOBYBgRBNO%2BPB2DIChgrxgmQG86FjwQVAryofHPmIJGIBcT6zpcexMlOI7ODOtATCFegAHlaFYTm0dILA2vEdgWfFvBFlSYykbFzAAA8UiOIZYZa1QZZOFxiA5gwsC597cxME3uhoegmDYDgeH4UJRHEFB7rkEQ8BcJHIG6VA5wCJWAFpyU4qQ5AUThGUR5JUi0CBrHqcxEmscpYniUJwn8OgE/T3xM9oFPKgSJJCjSZps8aaOihKLIC/aIulzqQxclCBuWhiQuuG6JQnoGIQDqO07zpl%2BGVYADi1AOtW4SZgGQVcIANIxaCBp8IFwQgSB/QRhEmAwSfcLeul313ZHelnvpB7fQ23m/b7viHBih0hzbBoexfhxHkdIVGvox7GICQFpLwRxyCUF5l4fGHQrD4CIB4YQVtGAsGlvbIqBsvAWwfoPGG10jojE4JMIqhAECTDHhPKeM856TAXsQJeK8z5o2%2Br9Zg/1KD90fmdF%2B4NsFwyOp/FG59ugg1fodQYb036ww/t/ARD9pDQ2HrwqRDDujGQZgEEA3AgA)

Comment: I'd like to accept all three answers as each of them does resolve the task and has it's own advantages. Accepting the simpler one as it suits my needs better, however, SFINAE application is also great.